# backup windows partitions with dd

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, dd

I am on Ubuntu, I have 2 external hard drives, of of them is an SSD. The HDD is from a laptop with windows 10 on it, the SSD is completely empty, I want to use it to copy everything on the HDD to the SSD. I'm using a powered usb 3.0 hub with 2 sata to USB 3.0 cables to connect the drives to  my computer.

I was going to this with dd but I realized windows has many partitions, sdb1(C:\ drive), sdb2(EFI system partition), sdb3 (Microsoft reserved partions), sdb4(basic data partition). How can I copy all of them to the SSD using dd?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve with the back-up? Do you want to be able to recover personal data or to boot the backed up version of the operating system on that drive?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Win10 HDD = `sda` and blank SSD = `sdc`

Rather than using `dd` for each individual partition, use it on the block device as a whole.

For example, rather than copying from `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` and so on, just copy from `/dev/sdb`

So you can do something like:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

Comment: I would but the hdd also has a cent os Linux partition which starts at dev/sda5 . I'd like to only copy windows and its partitions

Comment: @answerSeeker one thing you could do would be to save the partitions to `.img` files on the SSD